# WCF Security - Transport Level Security with username password

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I wish to provide security for a webservice.  I initially  used BasicHttpBinding with Transport security (ssl) and message security (to pass username and password for Custom Username Password Validation)...

But the consumers of the web service said they cant add a header to the soap message with security details.. and said they would like to pass it on the communication channel for the service.

Is it possible to do custom validation of user, with transport security with WCF??  I can't get it working :(

Any suggestions?

thanks
Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your consumers are asking for Basic Authentication. That is, where the authentication token is passed in the HTTP Authorization header rather than in the SOAP security header. Confidentiality of the credentials will be provided only by the transport (HTTPS).

The binding configuration for this is:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="HTTPSwithBasicAuthentication">
      <security mode="Transport">
         <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

On the client, you set the credentials like this

```
serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Assuming your service is hosted in IIS, remember to enable Basic Authentication in the IIS configuration.

To do the actual authorization of the users you will could implement a custom `ServiceAuthorizationManager` to contain your authorization logic. There are lots of examples of how to do that last part on the web.

Alternatively you could configure in a standard ASP.Net membership provider if that is appropriate for your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990(VS.100).aspx